# Unexpected EOF while Parsing In Russian Roulette

Tags: python

Im doing a little home project since I'm learning python (beginner) and I made my self a Russian roulette game and it comes up with Unexpected EOF while Parsing on the last line. So if some could help me out on whats going wrong I will be very thankful.

```
import random

print ("Welcome to Russian Roulette without guns :/ ")
amount = input("How many players? 2 or 3 or 4:")

if amount == ("2"):
     print ("Player 1 Name")
     player_1 = input(" ")
     print ("Player 2 Name")
     player_2 = input(" ")

     print (player_1)
     enter = input("Click Enter:")
if enter == (""):
    number = random.randint(1, 2)
    print (number)
    if number == 1:
        print (player_1)
        print ("You dead")
        print ("---------")
        print (player_2)
        print ("You win")

    else:
               print (player_2)
               enter_2 = input("Click Enter:")
               if enter_2 == (""):
                   number_2 = random.randint(1, 2)
                   if number_2 == 1:
                       print (player_2)
                       print ("You Lose")
                       print ("---------")
                       print (player_1)
                       print ("You win")


elif amount == ("3"):
     print ("Player 1 Name")
     player_1 = input(" ")
     print ("Player 2 Name")
     player_2 = input(" ")
     print ("Player 3 Name ")
     player_3 = input(" ")

     print (player_1)
     enter_3 = input("Click Enter:")
if enter_3 == (""):
    number_3 = random.randint(1, 1)
    print (number)
    if number == 3:
        print (player_1)
        print ("You Dead")
        print ("Your Out")
        print ("-------------")
        print ("{0}, {1} You are still in".format(player_1, player_2)
```

Comment: `print ("{0}, {1} You are still in".format(player_1, player_2)` has two left parentheses and one right parenthesis.

Comment: `print()` needs open *and* closing parentheses. Add the closing paren.

Comment: print ("{0}, {1} You are still in".format(player_1, player_2)  --- missing closing ")"

Answer (score 1):

On the last line, you are missing a closing parenthesis. It should be:

```
print ("{0}, {1} You are still in".format(player_1, player_2))
```

Answer (score 0):

EOF is end of file so it  usually an an unexpected termination of the program, which is most likely caused by one of a few things, in python: if you missed closing parentheses, or a missing ; in the last line/ line before (so it runs as one line with out the ;). however i can tell you that you are missing closing parentheses at the end of the last print statement. also just a small improvement i would suggest, comment your code python is quite easy to read but its good practice for languages that are not as easy to read.